# Auto refresh ItemTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, itemtemplateselector

I have `ItemsControl` with multi `DataTemplate` and use `ItemTemplateSelector` to chose appropriate `DataTemplate` of each item of `ItemsSource`. I want to binding `ItemTemplateSelector` to TemplateType dependency property of item. and each time TemplateType property changed, `DataTemplate` change automaticaly. How can I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Search about own question. and find below code to refresh `ItemTemplateSelector` :

```
DataTemplateSelector DataTemplateSelector = plan.ItemTemplateSelector;
plan.ItemTemplateSelector = null;
plan.ItemTemplateSelector = DataTemplateSelector;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for a different solution in your case, if you want to update the datatemplate.
I would create a binding to the ItemTemplate of your ItemsControl. That binding gets a converter assigned, which contains the logic of your current ItemTemplateSelector. And the source of the binding is your TemplateType property.

The ItemTemplateSelector is just for one-shot evaluation.

Comment: ItemTemplate is a property of ItemsControl and I cannot Bind Item to it.

Comment: what do you mean you cannot bind to it? <ItemsControl ItemTemplate={Binding Path=TemplateType,Converter={StaticResource yourconv}} ...

I know that does work, I used that pattern already

Comment: When I Use `ItemTemplate="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconv}}"`, get null value in converter function. I expect that get my item in converter function.

Comment: When I use above command, my converter function run only one time. But I want to chose template for each item in `ItemsSource` Items.

Comment: ok then create a datatemplate with just ContentControl and do the Binding to the Template property of that ContentControl. Then it will be evaluated per item.

Comment: I don't understand what I must doing. Please help me more.

Comment: <ItemsControl><ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><ContentControl ContentTemplate={Binding Path=TemplateType, Converter={StaticResource myconv}} /> ....

Comment: I cant get Answer. please edit your answer and write xaml code completely.