# Force reapply of ItemTemplateSelector in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView as my zoomed out view in a SemanticZoom control. This GridView uses a custom DataTemplateSelector as the ItemTemplateSelector. It shows an item for each content group that my app shows.

The template is different depending on whether the group is empty or not. This works fine on load, but it doesn't update when a group becomes empty or stops being empty.

I've found that the ItemTemplateSelector is only run when the page is first shown. How can I force the DataTemplateSelector get run again.

The WPF questions on this topic all suggest triggers, but these aren't available in WinRT XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to a similar WPF question that answers this in a way that works in WinRT:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327087/31569

Basically you set the ItemTemplateSelector to null and then set it again. Like this:

```
var templateSelector = MyGroupView.ItemTemplateSelector;
MyGroupView.ItemTemplateSelector = null;
MyGroupView.ItemTemplateSelector = templateSelector;
```

This works, but happy to be told if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I find it easier to just just remove the item in need updating from the collection and adding it back.  This forces the GridView or ListView to apply the template.  This is easy to do in MVVM world.

```
var itemToReload; //The object who's template needs updating
var reloadIndex  = this.SomeCollection.IndexOf(itemToReload);

this.SomeCollection.Remove(itemToReload);
this.SomeCollection.Insert(reloadIndex, itemToReload);
```

One thing to note, is that if the item is a "Selected" item, you'll need to reapply that selection.